# What is the correct way for an enemy to chase player?

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml

I created some code for the enemy sprite to follow the player, which works fine until it gets close to the player.  The problem is that when it gets quite close to the player, it begins to slow down.  Instead, I want it to maintain a constant speed.

```
distance = ((player.getPosition())- slime.getPosition());
slimeSprite.move((distance * speed * (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() / 60)));
```

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure how your code works in context, but it seems like `distance` would only account for the X or the Y direction, not the diagonal between the two. Could that potentially be an issue?\

Comment: Why is distance in formula if you want to move like player wasn't there?

Comment: Just normalize the `distance` vector.  Note that this may cause other issues, especially if the enemy ends up in exactly the same position as the player.  You may want to consider giving your enemy some kind of momentum, and using the direction vector to the player to affect the enemy's speed (also a vector).  Then update the enemy position based on its current speed only.

Comment: Distance is measured in metes (m); speed in m/s; time in seconds (s). You multiply them all. What do you get? m * m/s * s = m*m. Weird. Square meters? Just remove the `distance` from the formula, but then you risk that the sprite will be sometimes overlapping with the player.

Comment: I'm sure that this is just a poorly-named variable.  Assuming the positions are actually points, the calculation is actually returning a _direction_ vector from the "slime" to the player.  The proper approach would be to normalize this vector, creating a unit vector.  This can then be scaled by whatever speed is required and used to calculate the slime's new position.  So it would make sense if it was called `direction`, not `distance`.  In fact, `distance` would be the _length_ of the un-normalized direction vector, if that's required.  And it could be used to perform normalization.

Comment: @paddy I'm struggling to normalize the distance variable. Wouldn't it be ```normalized.x = sqrt(distance.x * distance.x);
    normalized.y = sqrt(distance.y * distance.y); ```

Comment: No, not at all.  Please learn basic vector math and Pythagoras' theorem.  The length of a 2D vector is `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`.  A unit vector is simply the original vector divided by its length.  _i.e._ `(x / length, y / length)`.  From a practical standpoint, be careful if your length is very close (or equal) to zero, as you'll likely run into problems with floating point precision or divide-by-zero.

Comment: @paddy okay that worked thanks, for the length being close to zero I'll implement a pixel collision test which moves back the player when the sprites touch. Also I do know basic vector math and pythagoras' theorem, it's just that it is impossible for me to do these calculations if I cannot visualize it

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is vector normalization. Because you are using the distance from the slime to the player in the move function, a lower distance value will result in the slime moving slower. Instead, you need a vector that points from the slime to the player with a constant distance. To calculate that vector, you can use the Pythagorean Theorum. As mentioned in the comments, sqrt(x * x + y * y), where x and y represent the distance between the slime and the player, will give you the magnitude of the Vector. Dividing the x and y of the distance by the magnitude will normalize it, which in this case is what you want. Here is an example of a function that takes in a vector, normalizes it, and returns the normalized vector:

```
sf::Vector2f normalize(sf::Vector2f vec) {
float magnitude = sqrtf(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y);
if (magnitude != 0) {
    vec.x /= magnitude;
    vec.y /= magnitude;
}
return vec;
}
```